# Vagrant user lost sudo permissions and services stop working

Tags: debian, vagrant

Default vagrant user can't use sudo and root access to server running on debian 10.

`sudo command not found`

When trying to use regular commands. Also LEMP services not working.

I have tried to login as root and check **visudo**, also added manually:

`vagrant ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL`

This not help. I don't change anything before this bug. What to do, to restore all as it was?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if the `sudo` package is not installed at all.

If you can still log in as root you can (re-)install it with

`apt-get install sudo`

(But this is not really a vagrant related question ...)

Comment: I login root to server via virtualbox and checked, sudo installed, vagrant is in sudoers file, but it's not working.

Comment: But you are getting `sudo command not found`, not something like `permission denied`.

So if the package is installed, the other two possible reasons would be that either the `/usr/bin/sudo` binary has somehow been removed, or that `/usr/bin` is not in `$PATH`. The later would be very unlikely though as you'd get `command not found` on most commands then ...

Comment: That's why I am asking here. Sudo commands working from root. I don't understand what happened with Vagrant user.

Comment: Does it really say `sudo command not found`?

This does not look like a verbatim output copy, there should be a colon in it. Can you share a copy/paste of the actual sudo command line and error message?